# Upload files in another domain on same server

Tags: php, yii

I need to move all uploaded files in domain , and all website will be in another domain
but in same server ip , so  how to  edit uploading process  to upload files 
directly to " Files domain " ?.

EX:

Site Domain : doamin.com

Files domain : myfiles.com

in normal way this my code :

View

```
 ...........
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'Cfiles-form',

            'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
            'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true), //This is very important


           'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    )); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'file'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'file'); ?>
            الملفات المسموحة : jpg,gif, png,pdf,rar,zip,doc,docx
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'file'); ?>
        </div>
    ...............
```

Controller

```
public function actionCreate()
    {

       ..................
.

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Cfiles']))
        {



            $model->attributes=$_POST['Cfiles'];
            $valdiate=$model->validate();


         /////// upload image functions 

         $rnd = rand(0,999984375);  // generate random number between 0-9999
         $model->attributes=$_POST['Cfiles']['file'];


            $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
        if(!empty($uploadedFile)){
            $ext=$uploadedFile->getExtensionName();
            $fileName = "isa$rnd.{$ext}";  // random number + file name
            }


             ////////// end 


            if($model->save()){

               $f_id=$model->primaryKey; 

               ................

                      if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                {
                 $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../cfillaf/'.$fileName);  // upload image to server 
                  $model->file = $fileName;

                  $model->save(false);
               }   

  ....................

        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just chge the file path and make sure the file\directory permissions allow this

Comment: Dagon : can you give me example?  thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Dagon means is:

```
$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../cfillaf/'.$fileName);
```

can be changed into:

```
$uploadedFile->saveAs('http://www.myfiles.com/my_writable_image_dir/'.$fileName);
```

Don't forget to make sure that myfiles.com/my_writable_image_dir/ is writable.

However, because both domains are on the same server, you can use the server path to access your image folder. Something like this:

```
$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../../../myfiles.com/public_html/my_writable_image_dir/'.$fileName);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: is it secure to use it in this way ?
$uploadedFile->saveAs('http://www.myfiles.com/my_writable_image_dir/'.$fileName);

Comment: it's return 
[<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: To use this function, you need to change the permissions of the file that you're writing to (777).

Comment: yes even public_html , but i guess I will have big security risk

Comment: the security risks when it comes to loose permissions on your directory structures is disputable, in otherwise it differs in different situations. You should check out this article: http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=2987.0

Comment: also, permissions are dependent on the user. that means that your could have changed your permission for your php user, but if you're using a different user, you still won't have permission to write. So please check your users + their permissions